# R How to perform multiple anovas and Post-Hoc-Test over a list of df´s?

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

how can I perform multiple `ANOVA´s` and `Post-Hoc-Tests` over a list of dataframes?
Assuming I have this type of data structure:

```
set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(Number = c("No1", "No2", "No3", "No1", "No2", "No3", "No1", "No2", "No3" ),
                  value = sample(1:200, 9))

df2 <- data.frame(Number = c("No4", "No5", "No6", "No4", "No5", "No6", "No4", "No5", "No6" ),
                  value = sample(1:200, 9))

df3 <- data.frame(Number = c("No7", "No8", "No9", "No7", "No8", "No9", "No7", "No8", "No9" ),
                  value = sample(1:200, 9))

df <- list(df1 = df1,df2 = df2,df3 = df3)
```

With one single df I am able to perform the anova and also perform the `HSD.test` from the package `agricolae`

```
library(agricolae)
ANOVA <- aov(value ~ Number, data = df1)
HSD_Test <- agricolae::HSD.test(y = ANOVA,
                                trt = "Number", 
                                group = TRUE,
                                console = TRUE,
                                alpha = 0.3)
graphics::plot(HSD_Test)
```

But how can I do this with multiple df´s in the list?
Ideally I would want to store the grouping variables (a,b,c etc) in a new column in the dataframes like this:

```
> df1
  Number value Group
1    No1    33     a
2    No2    18     a
3    No3     8     b
4    No1   164     a
5    No2    94     a
6    No3    37     b
7    No1   149     a
8    No2   118     a
9    No3    71     b
```

I do **not** want to combine the df´s in one big df and run then the ANOVA.

Comment: Write a function to perform your analysis on one data frame.  The function should take a data frame as its first (or only) argument.  Then pass this function as the second argument to `lapply`.  The first argument should be your list of dataframes, thus: `results <- lapply(df, myAnalysisFunction)`.  `results` will be a list whose elements are the objects returned by `myAnalysisFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should put you on your way:

```
set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(Number = c("No1", "No2", "No3", "No1", "No2", "No3", "No1", "No2", "No3" ),
              value = sample(1:200, 9))
df2 <- data.frame(Number = c("No4", "No5", "No6", "No4", "No5", "No6", "No4", "No5", "No6" ),
              value = sample(1:200, 9))
df3 <- data.frame(Number = c("No7", "No8", "No9", "No7", "No8", "No9", "No7", "No8", "No9" ),
              value = sample(1:200, 9))
df <- list(df1 = df1,df2 = df2,df3 = df3)

ex <- lapply(df,function(x) aov(value ~ Number, data = x))
```

Comment: Why not use the list of data frames has already provided by OP and avoid need for `tables` and the calls to `mget` and `list2env`?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I used that because it needed to source it to my current env, but that's  not necessary in this case. I modified my response, thanks!